# Css animations in ionic app not working in iOS simulator

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic-framework, webkit

I have a marquee in my app. It works in chrome, but when i start the app in the iOS Simulator, the animation is much slower and doesn't run trough.

The Ticker text runs in chrome from right to left and repeats.

In the iOS simulator it's too slow and the text moves about 30px from the right and then stops completely and starts again.

What's my mistake?

This is my CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
.ticker-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  padding-left: 100%;
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  padding-right: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
  animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
.ticker__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
  <div class="ticker-wrap">
      <div class="ticker">
        <div class="ticker__item">{{lt}}</div>
        <div class="ticker__item">{{lt}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```